# Tinymce addEventListener getElementsByClassName custom plugin

Tags: tinymce, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname, tinymce-plugins

Is it possible from a custom plugin to intercept the click on an element within the editor that has a certain class?

I register the new plugin

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('test', function (editor) {
```

I can only intercept a general click within the editor with this code

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('test', function (editor) {
    editor.on('click', function (e) {
    });
    .....
```

I would need to only intercept clicks to elements with a certain class.
It's possible?